# composer autoload vs zend framework universal autoloading

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

Based on your experience , which one would you say is faster, tidier and what would it be the main pros and cons between composer autoload or the universal autoloading of zend framework? to load say 3000 requires? I know maybe faster and tidier could be answered with a test . It'll be acceptable for me only with the pros and cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever dealt with the strangeness of why the f... your classes cannot be loaded because they were in the wrong folder where they do not belong?

That's what Zend autoloading is good for.

And the other reason: There is no autoloading besides the one provided by Composer by now. Yes, in theory you could write your own. But why? It's a solved problem, with probably the best (in all regards) generic solution.

So one pro for Composer, one con for Zend. And by the way, there is no Zend loader in ZF3 anymore - Composer got the job.